# Change MySql.data version in Global Assembly Cache (GAC)

Tags: c#, mysql, global-assembly-cache, mysql.data

So I have previously developed a payroll system using c# way back 2010, and I decided to use it again as a reference, I had its ClickOne Application Deployment Manifest, but when I tried to run it an error appears "Unable to install or run the application. the application requires that assembly MySQL.Data Version 5.1.7.0 be installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) first". when I check the GAC on windows/assembly, I had MySQL.Data version 6.2.2.0, Is there a way to change/uninstall this and install a version 5.1.7.0?

I had searched for a possible answer to my questions but most of the results is on publishing, unfortunately I cant republish the application again as I lost my sql database, any help will do as I will continue browsing for possible answer.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To install a dll into GAC from cmd ,use below commands.
First find the GAC path.Mostly the path will be

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly
```

Based on 32 or 64 bit,install it.Before everything download the MySQL.Data Version dll  5.1.7.0 and place it in a location folder.And install it using below command.

```
Gacutil -i C:\location\Mysqldata.dll
```

Will install the dll into the GAC. And both the version 5.1.7.0 and 6.2.2.0 will exist in GAC.

Comment: it says "Gacutil is not recognized as internal or external command"

Comment: I found the solution for gacutil, ill get back after I fix this, thanks

Comment: oh well, im still stuck with this gacutil thing, :(

Answer (score 1):

If you stuck finding gacutil in cmd "This tool is automatically installed with Visual Studio. To run the tool, use the Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio (or the Visual Studio Command Prompt in Windows 7). For more information, see Command Prompts." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/gacutil-exe-gac-tool